# Losing precision in stringstream

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy, stringstream, static-cast

In one of my applications I am trying to put a float value into a string stream like this:

```
stream << static_cast<float>(double value);
```

Instead of getting the entire float value I get only the integer part of it. Any idea why that might happen?

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more code so that people can see what's actually going on. As written, this code snippet can't compile. What value did you use, and what got written to the stream?

Answer (score -1):

You're casting to a `float` - which C++ defines as an [IEEE 754 32-bit 'single precision' floating point type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

If you look up the format of such a value, the 32 bits are split between three components:

- 23 bits to store the significand
- 8 bits to store the exponent
- 1 bit to store the sign.

If you have 23 bits to store the signifcand, that means the largest value you could represent in the significand is 2^23. As a result, single-precision floating points only have about 6-9 digits of precision.

If you have a floating point value that has 9 or more digits before the decimal point - if it exceeds 2^23 - you will never have a fractional component.

To help that sink in, consider the following code:

```
    void Test()
    {
        float test = 8388608.0F;

        while( test > 0.0F )
        {
            test -= 0.1F;
        }
    }
```

That code never terminates. Every time we try to decrement test by 0.1, the change in magnitude is lost because we don't have the precision to store it, so the value ends up right back at 8388608.0. No progress can ever be made, so it never terminates. This is true of all limited precision floating point types, so you'd find that this same problem would happen for IEEE 754 double precision floating point types (64-bit) all the same, just at a different, larger value.

Also, if your goal is to preserve as much precision as possible, then it does not make sense to cast from `double` to `float`. `double` is a 64-bit floating point type; `float` is a 32-bit floating point type. If you used double, you might be able to avoid most of the truncation if your values are small enough.

Comment: The C++ standard **does not** define `float` as an IEEE 754 type. That's quite common, but it is not required.

Comment: This answer does not address the question.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Could you clarify? A downvote and a single sentence "this is wrong" isn't exactly helpful, for anybody. Aside from my mistaken assumption about the entropy of the C++ `float` and `double` types, I don't understand your criticism. Am I wrong in stating that, above a certain limit, a float can no longer store values with fractional components? Am I wrong to assert that in this situation that is the problem? Have I read too much into the askers question for what is one of the most commonly experienced problems when dealing with floating point math?

Comment: @antiduh - read the question. While it's **possible** that the problem is that the value is too large, there's nothing in the question that shows that that's the case. There are far too many other possibilities to simply assert that that's the problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Would you be willing to name/describe one other possibility?

Comment: @antiduh - since there's no compilable code, pretty much anything is possible. Maybe the value being converted is 1, for example.

Comment: @PeteBecker - I understand that the asker has low karma and hasn't given a lot of detail. But: "maybe the value is 1" would seem to be contraindicated by the asker's question: "Instead of getting the entire float value I get only the integer part of it".

Comment: @antiduh - engineering is based on **knowledge**, not on guesses. There is not enough information here to make an informed judgment. There are many reasons a beginner might be wrong about the value of a number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103875/discussion-between-antiduh-and-pete-becker).